# Как сделать так чтобы при запуске Томката он сразу открывал баузер с нужным URL?

Tags: tomcat

Например
http ://localhost:8080/MyWebProject/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте батник (или шелл-скрипт), который будет вызывать батник (или шелл-скрип), запускающий томкат, а затем вызывать команду открытия страницы в браузере, вроде [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23039509/8343843).

Только имейте в виду, что время подготовки томкатом приложения может зависеть от многих факторов. Старт самого томката еще не означает, что приложение готово к использованию. Возможно, решением будет некоторая заданная пауза между запуском томката и открытием браузера.